# Limit Nginx Proxy redirection to a specific page and action

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a server that hosts several docker services, some of them are exposed to internet using Nginx Proxy Manager.

I want to create a proxy host for a specific page of a service, and only for this page.
I am struggling with the configuration.

I want to expose http://192.168.1.193:8080/?action=stream with stream.mydomain.com

I created a proxy host : [proxy host configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTEcV.png)

I works fine but everything at 192.168.1.193:8080 is obviously accessible.

How can I restrain the proxy to only give access to 192.168.1.193:8080/?action=stream ?
I tried various "custom locations" configuration and Advanced configuration without any success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.